# Delphi: Is there a refactoring tool to extract a class and its dependencies in a unit to a new unit?

Tags: delphi

I have a big unit contains many classes, and now I want to refactor that unit by separating certain classes into new units.

I have to admit that I'm lack of experience on using the Delphi built-in IDE features. Utilizing the built-in feature **"Find | Find Local References to Type "** didn't help much because the class methods use many unit-level vars, consts, types.

I'm looking for a refactoring tool that can help me to accomplish this easily, preferably an open source one, but sharewares ones are also welcome.

Comment: Do the refactorings that are built in to the Delphi IDE not suit your needs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always do that manually. Otherwise, you might consider a tool such as ModelMaker Code Explorer or ModelMaker, which supports Extract Class refactoring,

http://www.modelmakertools.com/code-explorer/features.html#explorer-refactorings

Comment: +1 Though it may not extract to another unit, once the class has been extracted it should be easy enough to move it to another unit using Modelmaker's code explorer.